# DatePicker validation for Date of Birth

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I want the user to be able to select a date that is at most 18 years from now(i.e users must be 18+ to apply).Here is what i tried thus far.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Date input --->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="date">DOB</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
        var container=$('.form-horizontal').length>0 ? $('.form-horizontal').parent() : "body";
        date_input.datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            endDate: '-18y',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            orientation: "top",
        })
    })
</script>
```

I tested with my following for `endDate` but none seems to work

`-18y`

`-18yyyy`

`18years`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working fine for me, please check, there might be some other changes that have affected. https://jsfiddle.net/ouy7Ldfw/

```
date_input.datepicker({
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
        endDate: '-18y',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        orientation: "top",
    })
```

Comment: I tried your solution but i get `(intermediate value).decrement is not a function` error